# count json lines dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, extjs4

I asked this question earlier this morning 
"here is my JSON file :

```
[
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "3_major",
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "4_minor",
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "4_minor",
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "4_minor",
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "4_minor",
    "From": "IN1"
},
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "4_minor",
    "From": "IN2"
},
{
    "Week": "1145",
    "Sev_Logged": "3_major",
    "From": "IN2"
},
];
```

I want to count the "from : IN1" field for each "week", per example for week : 1145 i'd get : 3, and for "From : IN2" i'd get 2

Thanks"

Thank you VDP for your answer, so I did this : 
My store is now like :

```
Ext.define('Metrics.store.GraphData', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
model : 'Metrics.model.GraphData',
autoload : true,

proxy : {
    type : 'ajax',
    url : 'data/metrics_data.json',
    reader : {
        type : 'json',
        root : 'data',
        successProperty : 'success'
    }
},
//data : GraphData, //povide inline data or load using proxy
countBy: function(param){
    var count = {};
    this.each(function(item){
        var type = item.get(param);
        if (Ext.isDefined(count[type])){
            count[type]++;
        } else {
            count[type] = 1;
        }                               
    });
    return count;
}
});
```

And my model :

```
Ext.define('Metrics.model.GraphData', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
//fields: ['week', 'sev']
fields : [ 
    {name: 'Week',  type: 'int'},
    {name: 'Sev_Logged',   type: 'string'},
    {name: 'From', type: 'string'}
]
});
```

Since i'm using extjs 4 with MVC model, I have made a controller wich controls the event of a button, right now it looks like this :

```
launchGraph : function(button){
console.log('clicked the apply button');
var chartStore = this.getGraphDataStore();
chartStore.load({
    callback: this.onGraphDataLoad,
    scope: this,
    console.log(chartStore.countBy("From"))
    });
```

But when I click the apply button I get this error in my controller :

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . "
```

And it points to the line :

```
 "console.log(chartStore.countBy("From"))"
```

It seems like i have an error in the referencing to my store. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you even know how to parse your JSON string into a JavaScript array of objects?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I am actually working with extjs 4, but I don't know how to parse my Json file. I use this data to render a chart so I need to count them.

Comment: Okay problem fixed by putting the "console.log(chartStore.countBy("From"))" line outside the chartStore.load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the array you provide you can just use the mimikomi's answer or a similar ExtJS version of it:

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/NvNVW/)

```
function countBy(data, param) {
    var count = {};
    Ext.each(data, function(item){
        var type = item[param];
        if (Ext.isDefined(count[type]))  {
            count[type]++;
        } else {
            count[type] = 1;
        }  
    });
    return count;
}
```

If you load that json from an external location it's best practice to load it in a store. You define a model, a store and add 'special' functions to your store for example.

```
Ext.define('Week', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'Week',  type: 'int'},
        {name: 'Sev_Logged',   type: 'string'},
        {name: 'From', type: 'string'}
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Week',
    data : data, //povide inline data or load using proxy
    countBy: function(param){
        var count = {};
        this.each(function(item){
            var type = item.get(param);
            if (Ext.isDefined(count[type])){
                count[type]++;
            } else {
                count[type] = 1;
            }                               
        });
        return count;
    }
});

var countObject = store.countBy("From");

alert(Ext.encode(countObject));
//chrome developper tools, safari, opera can show us the contents of objects in a log too. IE, FF however only tell us it is an object. (pretty useless)
console.log(countObject);
//you can chose you're favorite notation to retreve the value (but I hope you knew this, it's pretty basic javascript)
console.log(countObject.IN1); 
console.log(countObject['IN2']);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NvNVW/2/).

[More info](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json) on loading json dynamically into a store via ajax (using a proxy)

Comment: I have done everything you said, but the console returns : [Object object].

Comment: of course I return an object :) use chrome developer tools or `JSON.strigify(theobject)` or `Ext.encode(theobject)` to convert it in a readable string I'll update the fiddle

Comment: But both the countObject.IN1 and ccountObject['IN2'] return "undefined".

Comment: No it doesn't... it returns 5 and 2. You must have changed something... Or you're working on an ancient (retarded) browser (IE8 or lower) in that case console.log isn't present. Replace by alerts to see what's going on.. Or upgrade your browser to the latest version. (Recommended)

Comment: I'm using chrome, I had to put them in Ext.encode to work. 
Another question please, do you have any idea on how to loop through IN1 and IN2 for each week ? I'm really new to javascript and extjs, and I want a result like : "for week 1145 you have IN1=1 and IN2=2 and for week 1146 you have IN1 = 1 and IN2=2".
Is it possible? I tried many things but nothing works.

Comment: No problem! Make sure you got the hang of javascript before you dive into ExtJs too deep. Object and string manipulation are basic js things. Once you're on your way, the sky is the limit! I made a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/NvNVW/5/) for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

If `var jsonData` is the array resulting from parsing the json shown above, this will give you an object with the counts of each depending on the parameter you use..

```
function CountBy(parameter) {
  var count = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
  var type = jsonData[i][parameter];
    if (count[type] === undefined)  {
      count[type] = 1;
    } else {
      count[type]++;
    }  
  }
  return count;
}
```

Result:

```
CountBy("From") => {"IN1" : 5, "IN2" : 2}
CountBy("Week") => {"1145" : 7}
CountBy("Sev_Logged") => {"3_major": 2, "4_minor": 5}
```

Comment: Just a clarification: if it's JSON, it's a string, not an array.

Comment: Well, call JSON.parse on the string first to get the data: `var jsonData = JSON.parse('[.........]');`

Comment: Thank you for answering, but I'm using extjs (sorry I didn't mention it in the question), is there a way to loop through my store without having to convert my json file to a javascript array ?

Comment: Seems there's a decoder you can use with Ext: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.JSON